# Magento 2 - add static reset css just before head close

Tags: magento2, css

I want to use a static css to reset my theme css, i cant modify main files because its paid theme and it will be auto reset at time of update.

So I need to add a static css just before  (head close) so it could reset all top css.

**I know how to add by : default_head_blocks.xml** but that is adding css at the top of .

i want to use it like this js example:

```
 <referenceContainer name="before.body.end">
      <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Js\Components" name="js.beforebody" as="jsbeforebody" template="Magento_Theme::js/js.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
```

Answer (score 0):

I deal this case like this:
Write your custom CSS in a *custom.css* -file and load this file normally in the head.

All classes you want to override can be overwritten on this way:

**bought.css:**

```
.class {
color: red
}
```

the !important -element is overwriting an existing definition.

**custom.css:**

```
.class {
color: blue !important;
}
```

or

```
body div.class {
color: blue;
}
```

The more specific you call the css the higher the chance to overwrite.